# Security flaws : How to avert them?

Tags: java, javascript, security, jsp, jstl

I am in  a bit of a pickle :

I have a lot of values which i am setting in  a bean in java and then i am getting them in javascript and jsp using scriplets like this :

**In My Bean.java :**

```
public void setListValue(String s) {   listValue = s;    }
public String getListValue()       {   return listValue;     }
```

**Now in my jsp(inside a javascript function) :**

```
input = $input({type:'hidden',id:'ListVal',name:'ListVal',
value: '<%= results.getListValue() %>'});
```

Sometimes i am using the scriplet code to retrieve parametres in jsp as well.

Normally if a parameter is passed from java file to java file or from jsp file to jsp file , then i use native java encoder and decoder like this :

```
     EncodedHere = URLEncoder.encode(encodedStr,"UTF-8");
     DecodedHere = URLDecoder.decode(EncodedHere,"UTF-8");
```

This works flawlessly for those scenarios but if  i have set my variables in java and then i try to retrieve them in javascript or jsp like the afore mentioned way , it fails. I have tried the **JSTL** way as well , but could not make it work, seems JSTL is not suitable to get values in javascript. Now this scriplet has been flagged as security concern by many. Since it's a huge code base it's very difficult to change that as well.

Does some one have any ideas as to avert this security flaw somehow. In other words, is there a way i can encode the variable in java and get the encoded string in jsp and javascript and then decode it ?

Comment: Why is this a security flaw? Your javascript is being built up on the server the pushed to the client by doing <%= results.getListValue() %> you are saying run this on the server BEFORE it goes to the client. Surely you want the client to be able to actually see there values on the screen ... I don't see the point of encoding server side and decoding client side. If you want this connection to be secure use https (ssl).

Comment: Well according to the security guys, some malicious value injection can be done here, in case scriplet coding is used to retrieve the values, hence the drag .

Comment: This: <%= results.getListValue() %> is on the server so no code injection there unless server code has injection errors. If you mean that when these values go back to the server they can have been modified, if this is an input field then the user can change the value that's the point? If you mean in-between then this is always the case regardless of this code or not, using https for a connection stops this problem. You can always snoop on a clients data and change any data if you have access to the pipe their data is on. Using an https connection means it's difficult to modify.

Comment: This is related to cross site blues .

Comment: Ah yes xss you just need to escape it correctly nevermind if only I'd have known I thought you where talking about something else. Where I currently am working they are worried about people hacking into the requests and changing data so this was at the forefront of my thoughts sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your security guys are worried about XSS (cross site scripting) attacks, which means data entered by the user that is re-displayed on a page could have malicious code in it. If that is the case you actually don't want to URL encode the data, you want to XML escape it, i.e replace potentially dangerous characters like `<` with their corresponding character entity like `&lt;`. To do this in JSP you can use the `<c:out>` tag or the `fn:escapeXML` EL function.  This works perfectly fine in javascript code, even if it is a little ugly. In your case it would look something like this:

First escape the javascript before you put it on the request using an escaping library the ESAPI reference implementation:

```
String jsEscapedValue = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForJavaScript(results.getListValue());
request.setAttribute("listValue", jsEscapedValue);
```

Then on the page use the `<c:out>` tag to HTML/XML escape it:

```
var myJsValue = '<c:out value="${listValue}"/>';
```

Make sure jstl.jar is on the classpath and be sure to include the correct tag lib at the top of your page.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Comment: Yes exactly, that sounds about right. I am gonna check this right away. Thanks a lot .

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, if i could have up voted it 100 times, i would have . Up voted and accepted .

Comment: If you output into a JavaScript string literal then the escaping you need is JS-escaping, *not* XML/HTML escaping. (Though if that JavaScript is itself in HTML, you may need HTML escaping as well afterwards...) For example, if the last character in the string is `\`, that *won't* get escaped and the string literal will saty open, breaking the script. Easiest way to JS-encode is to use a JSON encoder.

Comment: bobince is absolutely correct, you also want to javascript escape the value before you drop it on the request. A good XSS escaping library is the [ESAPI reference implementation](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/downloads/list). I updated the answer to include an example. Check out this [XSS cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for a good reference on preventing XSS attacks.

Comment: @clav : Thanks a lot, deeply appreciated .